# Making a smart class factory in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now with little success.  I'm attempting to write a class factory that plays nice with Django's ORM, so that I can take a model schema like this:

```
Product
    SubclassOfProduct0
    SubclassOfProduct1
    ....
```

To work like this:

```
Product.objects.get(pk=7) // returns the result of SubclassOfProduct0(pk=7)
Product.objects.filter(propname="w00t") // returns a QuerySet of Product objects
```

So I was thinking something like this:

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, *a, **kwa):
        # Get the id from Products (somehow)
        if product.type == Product.TYPE_SUBCLASS0:
            return ProductSubClass0.objects.get(pk=kwa["pk"])


class Product(models.Model):

    TYPE_SUBCLASS0 = 0
    TYPE_SUBCLASS1 = 1

    objects = ProductManager()

    def __init__(self, *a, **kwa):
        self.set_defaults()

    def set_defaults(self):
        pass


class ProductSubClass0(models.Model):
    def set_defaults(self):
        self.type == self.TYPE_SUBCLASS0
```

...but I don't know how to do it "right".  Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: Don't do this.  You don't need to write a factory.  Just create the hierarchy and create the objects via the ORM.

Comment: Normally, I would agree, but if I don't it forces me to put this kind of logic all over my views when I need additional information about an object and only have the id.  For example, in REST call, the user supplies pk=7 and I have to return an instance of ProductSubClass.

Comment: Do the ProductSubClasses have the same fields as Product class ?

Comment: Nope.  Product has a core set of properties which the subclasses share (id, name, description, etc.), but the subclasses all have different properties like battery life, or designer name, etc.

Comment: In ProductManager, where does product.type comes from ?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like for the get() call to make an initial query to the Products table for the type, then use that type to determine the class to use in the actual query.

Comment: @Daniel Quinn: "when I need additional information about an object and only have the id" This is an avoidable problem.  An ounce of design could save a pound of programming.  Why mess with this subclass foolishness when you could simply provide the proper object class as part of REST URL path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django Tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) has a great example in the models.py as to how it figures out the content type of specific classes. I'm currently using the pattern in another module I developed with permissions.

Comment: This actually helped a lot more than I thought it would.  I ended up writing a method called acquire() into a new ProductManager() which selected `type` from the db where pk=<n>.  Then, with that, I imported the appropriate class and returned the output of ProductSubClass0.objects.get(pk=n)

Answer (score 0):

You could just subclass your `Product`, as documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

```
class OtherProduct(Product):
    battery_life = …
```

Maybe also make `Product` an abstract base class if you don’t need to use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use entity framework with generic relations. For example, in models.py:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

# Product
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True)
    productDescription = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


#Shirt Product type
class ShirtProduct(models.Model):
    product  = generic.GenericRelation(Product)



#Book Product type
class BookProduct(models.Model):
    product  = generic.GenericRelation(Product)
```

....

For search one product id, you can use this method in your ProductManager:
    product = generic.GenericRelation(Product,
                                   content_type_field='content_type_fk',
                                   object_id_field='object_primary_key')

(reverse generic relations in the same section of [djangoproject page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations))